# How do I get a variable to change value in a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the variable `Intadd` to change from the number 0, but I can't because `Intadd` is in the function, causing it to remain 0 no matter what. I tried moving the variable `Intadd` outside of the function, but then it says that `Intadd` is already refferenced before assignment (the only time `Intadd` is run in my whole code is in this function).

```
dictfile = open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()

def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        Intadd = 0
        print(Intadd)
        if x.replace("\n", str(Intadd)) == Password:
            print("Congrats, you found the password!")
            break
        else:
            while Intadd < 10:
                Intadd += 1
```

Thanks for the help, you guys are lifesavers!

Comment: Try to manipulate with 'global' keyword:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function lies in the fact that you are setting the value of `Intadd` on every iteration of the loop. Here's a possible alternative:

```
def number_finder():  # I've taken the liberty of re-writing with more Pythonic naming conventions
    intadd = 0
    for x in dictionary_words:
        print(intadd)
        if x.replace('\n', str(intadd)) == password:
            print('Congratulations...')
            break
        # et cetera
```

However, I have a feeling that this might still not do exactly what you hope it to. That little `while` loop inside the `else` block has exactly the same effect as just setting `Intadd` to 10. Additionally, since `Intadd` is entirely contained inside the function, as soon as the function has returned, its current value will be lost. This could be solved with the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) or by returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the wrong end of the stick here but you can simply `return` `Intadd` from the function.
For example:

```
dictfile = open('wordsEn.txt', 'r')
#DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()
DictionaryWords = ['hello\n', 'world\n', 'password\n', 'Quality\n', 'guess\n', '\n']
Password = "Quality5"

def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        for Intadd in range(10):
            if x.replace("\n", str(Intadd)) == Password:
                return Intadd
    return 0

Password_attempts = Number_Finder()

if Password_attempts != 0:
    print ("Congratulations, you found the password! In",Password_attempts,"attempts")
else:
    print ("Password not found")
```

Result:

```
Congratulations, you found the password! In 5 attempts
```